# Visual Studio 2008 New Web site always creates a solution folder

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I create anew Web site project in VS it creates another folder for a solution file.

\WebSiteName\
\WebSiteName(2)\

In my VS solution explorer it only shows as a Web Site project, no solution file above it.  Is there a way I can stop VS creating the solution file when all I want is a web site?  Or is it something VS needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option not to create the solution folder is only available when using New Project. New Website always assumes you want a solution folder and by design is working correctly. If you don't want the folder then use New Project.

Visual Studio however does always require a solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it always needs a SLN file. Even if not used. If you open a project file it will create a blank/temp container solution.